# Select nos itens que nao foram inseridos

Tags: mysql

Seguinte, Tenho itens da tabelaA no caso lista de solicitações para alugar um dvd
A TabelaB sera inserido qual dvd vou alugar, sendo assim preciso selecionar a lista de dvds que nao foram alugados na TabelaA ou seja só me traga os itens que nao estão dentro da TabelaB.

TabelaA
TabelaB

A TabelaB vai receber os dados da TabelaA
preciso selecionar os itens da TabelaA que ainda nao estao dentro da TabelaB.

Comment: Pode detalhar um pouco a estrutura das tabelas?

Comment: Seguinte, Tenho itens da tabelaA no caso lista de solicitações para alugar um dvd A TabelaB sera inserido qual dvd vou alugar, sendo assim preciso selecionar a lista de dvds que nao foram alugados na TabelaA ou seja só me traga os itens que nao estão dentro da TabelaB

Answer (score 0):

Simulando o seu caso com as seguintes estruturas de tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE Dvds(`id` int, `nome` varchar(29));

CREATE TABLE DvdsAlugados(`id_dvd` int, `id_usuario` int);
```

É possível selecionar quais não estão alugados das seguintes maneiras:

```
select dvd.* from Dvds dvd
left join DvdsAlugados a on a.id_dvd = dvd.id
where a.id_usuario is null;
```

Ou:

```
select * from Dvds where id not in(select id_dvd from DvdsAlugados);
```

Pode ver esse funcionando no [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edd9f/1)

Comment: SELECT se.codemprestimo, se.dataemprestimo, se.horaemprestimo, se.codigo_socio_solicitou_emprestimo, se.dvd_codigo, se.socio_codigo, e.solicitacaoemprestimo_socio_codigo
FROM solicitacaoemprestimo se, emprestados e
WHERE se.socio_codigo = ? AND NOT e.solicitacaoemprestimo_socio_codigo = se.socio_codigo
ORDER BY dataemprestimo ASC, horaemprestimo ASC ;

Comment: como vocês colocam editado... caramba... hahahhahahaha